# python lxml.html: proper way to iterate through text with .tail in docstring order

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml, lxml.html

I'm trying to traverse an html string and concatenate the text content, with a string joiner that varies with the type of html tag encountered.

Example html:
`html_str='<td><p>This is how<br>we<br><strong>par<sup>s</sup>e</strong><br>our string</p> together</td>'`

I wrote a helper function called `smart_itertext()` to traverse an html element `e` via the method `e.iter()`.  For each `tag` in `e.iter()`, it checks the tag and then appends the .text or .tail content.

My challenge is making the tail text show up in the right place.  When I iterate by tag, I reach `<p>` and this appears to be my only chance to access the trailing text 'together'.

Desired result:

```
>>>smart_itertext(lxml.html.fromstring(html_str))
'This is how::we::parse::our string::together'
```

Actual result:

```
>>>smart_itertext(lxml.html.fromstring(html_str))
'This is how:: together::::we::parse::::our string'
```

This is my function:

```
def smart_itertext(tree, cross_joiner='::'):
empty_join= ['strong','b','em','i','small','marked','deleted',
            'ins', 'sub','sup']
cross_join = ['td','tr','br','p']
output=''
for element in tree.iter():
    if element.tag in empty_join:
        if element.text:
            output += element.text
        if element.tail:
            output += element.tail
    elif element.tag in cross_join:
        if element.text:
            output += cross_joiner + element.text
        else:
            output += cross_joiner
        if element.tail:
            output += cross_joiner + element.tail
    else:
        print ('unknown tag in smart_itertext:',element.tag)
return output
```

What's the proper way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use xpath, which allows you to build a list of content text as it occurs in document order, with attributes is_tail and is_text, and method getparent().

from [lxml.html tutorial:](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html)

> Note that a string result returned by XPath is a special 'smart'
>   object that knows about its origins. You can ask it where it came from
>   through its getparent() method, just as you would with Elements:
>
> ```
> >>> texts = build_text_list(html)
> >>> print(texts[0])
> TEXT
> >>> parent = texts[0].getparent()
> >>> print(parent.tag)
> body
>
> >>> print(texts[1])
> TAIL
> >>> print(texts[1].getparent().tag)
> br
> ```
>
> You can also find out if it's normal text content or tail text:
>
> ```
> >>> print(texts[0].is_text)
> True
> >>> print(texts[1].is_text)
> False
> >>> print(texts[1].is_tail)
> True
> ```

Comment: Can you expand on "use xpath"? How exactly did you produce the desired result stated in the question?